# How to programatically execute search in Role Manager

Tags: c#, sitecore

I currently have a solution that uses the Role Manager UI to "Rename" a role. When the user clicks "rename" in the ribbon, a couple prompts allow them to rename the role via stored proc. My goal is to simply display the new role name in the grid after renaming. When a user renames, the grid behind the prompts shows the last name of the role so they have to rerun the search for the grid to show a refreshed role name.

How do I programatically execute the search for the new role name so it displays in the grid after the user clicks OK on the last prompt?

Comment: I would make an attempt using javascript to activate one of the methods you find if you inspect the search box of the Role Manager UI: `<input onsubmit="return false;" onkeypress="return !Roles.SearchCheckEnter(event)" id="Roles_searchBox" class="SearchBox" onkeyup="Roles.SearchKeyHandler(event,this);" type="text" maxlength="20" size="20" value="">`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try executing:

```
ajaxScriptManager.Dispatch("rolemanager:refresh");
```

This should invoke the command to refresh the grid.